# How to determine timestamp for my rtp session?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, rtp

I am using rtp protocol in order to stream audio/video between 2 endpoints. I am having problem 
on determine the timestamp unit and the timestamp increment value.
I read that the timestamp unit is a formula of 1/samplerate. Is it right?
How do i determine the timestamp increment value?

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp is not strictly derived from any formula, but need to follow next rules:

- Timestamps should be derived from monotonic linear clock
- The resolution of the clock must be sufficient for sync accuracy

So, you don't have to use samplerate for this, but usually everyone do.
For example, when I stream sound with 16kHz freq in packets 20 ms each, I use following timestamps: 0, 320, 640,.. e.t.c, but I could use 0, 3200, 6400 in the same way.
Btw, standard suggest using random initial offset for timestamp, so you can start, for example, with N and use, N, N+320, N+640... More of the RTP standard, timing and so on [here](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt)

And one important thing. If you send media data, you should find document, which describes, how to use RTP protocol to send this data. For example, [H264](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184), [mp3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5219), and so on. It may strict the rules of how RTP header should be used. For example RTP timestamp frequency for H264 MUST be 90000.